# Fetching data from database using SSRS web service

Tags: web-services, ssrs-2012

Is there a way to fetch data from database by executing query without running any report using SSRS web service?

Answer (score 0):

No.  this is not possible.

You may need to explain what/why you want to do this to get a better response.

If you have access to the server to deploy a report, the report could be a very simple table that could be exported to excel.
If you cant deploy a report to use in this manner, then maybe there's a good reason for that? certainly security would be high on the list.